# Android using PhoneGap Cache the data file

Tags: android, cordova, cache-control

I have an android application (in dev), which    while starting reads 
a data file from the external server (say www.google.com/data.js). It 
checks with my SQL lite database and if the versions doesn;t match, 
then it updates the SQLITE. 
The problem now is, in the emulator, the data.js file gets cached up. 
Only when i uninstall the application it actually loads the new data. 
How do i avoid caching the JS file?

Answer (score 0):

add a random number as querystirng to the javascript call, so the andorid considers the files as new one each time it loads. 
Eg: 
myURL = 'www.mysite.com/data.js?' + Math.random();
$.getScript(myURL, function(){});

This way my jquery will load the file each time the application starts.